# Cannot get FullCalendar to work (Laravel 5)

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, fullcalendar, laravel-5

I'm quite new at Laravel 5 and I've been trying to follow the instructions on Github to install the full calendar (stated on: https://github.com/maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar)

Currently I simply want to display the calendar on my site, so I did the following:

Installed the plugin through composer with: 'composer require maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar' & added an alias to my app.php.

Next I made a interface that extends Eloquent\Model like this: (For when I add Events to my database):

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class EventModel extends Model \MaddHatter\LaravelFullcalendar\IdentifiableEvent{

    //fillable = Being able to mass assign (MassAssignment exception)

    protected $dates = ['start', 'end'];
    /**
     * Get the event's id number
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId();

    /**
     * Get the event's title
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Is it an all day event?
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isAllDay()
    {
        return (bool)$this->all_day;
    }

    /**
     * Get the start time
     *
     * @return DateTime
     */
    public function getStart()
    {
        return $this->start;
    }

    /**
     * Get the end time
     *
     * @return DateTime
     */
    public function getEnd()
    {
        return $this->end;
    }

}
```

Then in my controller I added:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CalendarController extends Controller {

$events[] = \Calendar::event(
    'Event One', //event title
    false, //full day event?
    '2015-06-05T0800', //start time (you can also use Carbon instead of DateTime)
    '2015-06-05T0800', //end time (you can also use Carbon instead of DateTime)
    0 //optionally, you can specify an event ID
);

$eloquentEvent = EventModel::first(); //EventModel implements MaddHatter\LaravelFullcalendar\Event  

$calendar = \Calendar::addEvents($events) //add an array with addEvents
    ->addEvent($eloquentEvent, [ //set custom color fo this event
        'color' => '#800',
    ])->setOptions([ //set fullcalendar options
        'firstDay' => 1
    ])->setCallbacks([ //set fullcalendar callback options (will not be JSON encoded)
        'viewRender' => 'function() {alert("Callbacks!");}'
]); 

return view('pages.calendar', compact('calendar'));

}
```

After doing this, is says on the instructions that I have to add the following to my view (which is in my folder: resources/pages/calendar.blade.php):

```
@extends('masterpage')
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.7/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.7/fullcalendar.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.7/fullcalendar.print.css"/>


@section('content')

<h1> Calendar </h1>
{!! $calendar->calendar() !!}
{!! $calendar->script() !!}
@stop
```

I also did '$bower install fullcalendar' in my project to add them.

Also, here is my folder structure, seeing I might have missed something:
[image: folder structure]

After following all these steps, it says the calendar should display but I'm getting this error:
[image: Undefined variable: calendar]

It's probably me just being stupid, but how do I fix this?

Comment: Just for testing, instead of doing view('your.view', compact('calendar')); can you do this : view('your.view')->withCalendar($calendar) and tell us if this works ?

Comment: It gives the same error.

Comment: try this, return view('pages.calendar', ['calendar' => $calendar]);

Comment: @Cedric did you get it to work eventually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you eventually get this to work?

I just had some problems implementing myself and thought I'd add my experiences in resolving this.

This worked for me using laravel 5.1 and mysql (mariadb) on fedora.

1. Model looks like the following (copied from https://github.com/maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar) with changes to the following line from

> class EventModel extends Eloquent implements
>   \MaddHatter\LaravelFullcalendar\Event

to

> class EventModel extends Model implements
>   \MaddHatter\LaravelFullcalendar\Event

2. Added the following lines to the controller

> use App\EventModel; use MaddHatter\LaravelFullcalendar\Event;

3. For db events add this inside the controller

> ```
> $event = EventModel::all();
>
> foreach ($event as $eve) {
>   $events[] = \Calendar::event(
>   $eve->title, //event title
>   $eve->allDay, //full day event?
>   $eve->start, //start time (you can also use Carbon instead of DateTime)
>   $eve->end, //end time (you can also use Carbon instead of DateTime)
>   $eve->id //optionally, you can specify an event ID
>   );
> }
> ```

4. If you work with blade templating I had to add the scripts to both my master and calendar pages (if removed from one it wouldn't show the calendar)
5. Dirty easy routing

> Route::resource('calendar','CalendarController');

I'm new to laravel so I know there could be easier ways or I didn't follow conventions, but this is how I got it to work so far, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the code in your controller isn't in a method:

```
class CalendarController extends Controller {

    public function index() { //code should be inside a method
        $events[] = \Calendar::event(
            'Event One', //event title
            false, //full day event?
            '2015-06-05T0800', //start time (you can also use Carbon instead of DateTime)
            '2015-06-05T0800', //end time (you can also use Carbon instead of DateTime)
            0 //optionally, you can specify an event ID
        );

        $eloquentEvent = EventModel::first(); //EventModel implements MaddHatter\LaravelFullcalendar\Event  

        $calendar = \Calendar::addEvents($events) //add an array with addEvents
            ->setOptions([ //set fullcalendar options
                'firstDay' => 1
            ])->setCallbacks([ //set fullcalendar callback options (will not be JSON encoded)
                'viewRender' => 'function() {alert("Callbacks!");}'
        ]); 

        return view('pages.calendar', compact('calendar'));
    }

}
```

Update:

Your `EventModel`'s `getId()` method needs to have body as well (i.e.: it needs to have an opening/closing `{` and `}`, and do something):

```
/**
 * Get the event's id number
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getId() {
    return $this->id;
}
```

The readme.md for the project was missing an example body.

Update 2:

```
class EventModel extends Model \MaddHatter\LaravelFullcalendar\IdentifiableEvent
```

should be

```
class EventModel extends Model implements \MaddHatter\LaravelFullcalendar\IdentifiableEvent
```

Comment: This still gives the same error. I also added 'use App\EventModel' seeing I hadn't added that.

Comment: @CedricBongaerts Your route looks like it's using `PagesController@calendar`, but the controller code in your question is from `CalendarController`. Try updating your routes.php file to use the right controller/method (it's in the format `<ControllerName>@<method>`)

Comment: The calendar seems to be initialized and wants to load, but now I'm getting this error:
'Non-abstract method App\EventModel::getId() must contain body'

Comment: Yes, I had already added that, but once adding the function/body it gave this error: 'Class 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model\MaddHatter\LaravelFullcalendar\IdentifiableEvent' not found'

Comment: I've held this aside for a bit to work on other stuff in my project but it's time for me to configure the calendar. The calendar shows the sample view posted.
I dont seem to have the buttons through the header even though when I browse to the Calendar.php it contains the code:

protected $defaultOptions = [
'header' => [
'left' => 'prev,next today',
'center' => 'title',
'right' => 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay',
],
'eventLimit' => true,
];

Is there a reason why it's not showing the buttons in the header?
Also, for some reason it only shows the first Event that I make in the database.